# Multiple functions with different return values llvm ir code

Tags: malloc, llvm, llvm-ir

#### Question

How can I access an external function (`malloc`) that has multiple possible return values? With malloc, I would like to be able to use it to get a pointer to an array and an array of arrays as is shown below. What is the best way to do this?

#### IR Code

```
declare [4000 x double]* @malloc(i64)

declare [4000 x [4000 x double]]* @malloc(i64)
```

#### Error

```
out.ll:3:35: error: invalid redefinition of function 'malloc'
declare [4000 x [4000 x double]]* @malloc(i64)
                                  ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: signature for malloc is "declare noalias i8* @malloc(i64)". you may have to cast it to [4000x[4000xdouble]]

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @ChiragPatel Thanks for the help! I will try that and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: @ChiragPatel I don't see the need for a loop. Unless I'm missing something, just allocating `4000 * 4000 * 8` bytes and casting the resulting pointer to `[4000 x [4000 x double]]*` should work as intended (unless the declared type is a mistake and the intended type is really `[4000 x [4000 x double]*]*`).

Comment: @sepp2k yes you are right. My bad.

Comment: Is there any reason that `malloc` would return type `[4000 x [4000 x double]*]*`? and if so would I then need to use a loop? Also, without the loop should I just use `CreatePointerCast`? Thank you both so much for the help!

Comment: Also If either of you want to put that as an answer I would accept it.

Comment: Got it working with `BitCastInst`. Thanks both of you!